# How to read Logback configuration file from path outside the war file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, logback

I have a requirement where I want to place all logback configuration outside the war file.
Presently I have placed my configuration file (logback.xml) on the classpath.
I am using the JBOSS EAP web application server, kindly suggest how to achieve the same.

Comment: Please see the answer in the page.
Wish it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349088/how-to-read-logback-configuration-file-from-system-environment-in-tomcat-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the jboss startup/run script and add this option:

java **-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml** chapters.configuration.MyApp1

see more at http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `-Dlogging.config=/path/to/logback.xml`

This is really handy with java based microservices to provide logging XML externally.