# How to read logback configuration file from system environment in tomcat 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, logback

Let me tell the story first:

We have 2 j2ee web applications AAA and BBB, and we want to put them in the same server.

Right now they both have the logback.xml in their class path, which is in /src/main/resources for the maven project.

We want to put all the configuration files in a directory, such as ${app_home}, and let the web applications to find their configuration files by themselves.

Like we put AAA_logback.xml and BBB_logback.xml into ${app_home}, and let the web application to find them automatically.

We use Tomcat 7 to deploy the web applications, if we want to achieve this, do we need any change on Tomcat 7 configuration?

There is a similar question:
[How to read Logback configuration file from path outside the war file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339446/how-to-read-logback-configuration-file-from-path-outside-the-war-file)

I wish I ask my question clearly with my poor English.

Comment: I would suggest you to keep the original logback.xml in the respective classpaths itself and include the actual stuff from ${app_home}/...
see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion In this way you can specify different files for different apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep the original logback.xml in the respective classpaths itself and include the actual stuff from ${app_home}/...

see [www.logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion](http://www.logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion)

In this way you can specify different files for different apps.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer after realizing it helped solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This is the right way to solve the question.