# Logback include configuration not working with relative path

Tags: java, tomcat, logback, slf4j

I am trying to place logback configuration outside war file and for this i hhave placed the logback file in the **webapps** folder to tomcat 7.

- Project name : **AnalyticsAPI**
- Path of logback.xml(the file inside the war) : `/webserv/apache-tomcat-7.0.55_1/webapps/AnalyticsAPI/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`
- Path of external logback with actual configuration : `/webserv/apache-tomcat-7.0.55_1/webapps/logback/logback-new.xml`

The logback.xml in war is :

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
   <include file="../logback/logback-new.xml" />
</configuration>
```

I have given above path since i read the article that path should be relative to **current working directory** and current working directory in this case should be the context root of project(if i am right)

The error i am getting in the logs is :

```
12:41:09,834 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@65b17009 - Adding 
[file:/home/users/roshnig/../logback/logback-new.xml] to configuration watch list.
12:41:09,835 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - 
Failed to open [file:/home/users/roshnig/../logback/logback-
new.xml]
```

Comment: You know you can use a property to tell logback where the config is (no need to "include"), see https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339446/how-to-read-logback-configuration-file-from-path-outside-the-war-file?rq=1

Comment: cannot do this since multiple applications are running on the server

Comment: also i need to use relative path and not absolute path